# Temasys android integration issue: "No value for version" V0.9.5

Tags: android, webrtc, skylink, temasys

I have integrated [Temasys lib](https://temasys.com.sg/) to integrate Video calling feature. everything was working fine but suddenly stop. Following error log I'm facing while connecting for room after connection made between sender and receiver:

> [onMessage] error: No value for version
>                                                  org.json.JSONException: No value for version
>                                                      at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
>                                                      at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
>                                                      at sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.cw.process(Unknown Source)
>                                                      at sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.bg.onMessage(Unknown Source)
>                                                      at sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.bj.onMessage(Unknown Source)
>                                                      at sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.bn.call(Unknown Source)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket.onevent(Socket.java:317)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket.onpacket(Socket.java:280)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket.access$100(Socket.java:18)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket$2$2.call(Socket.java:101)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Manager.ondecoded(Manager.java:382)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Manager.access$1200(Manager.java:21)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Manager$3.call(Manager.java:356)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.parser.Parser$Decoder.add(Parser.java:156)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Manager.ondata(Manager.java:374)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Manager.access$1000(Manager.java:21)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Manager$2.call(Manager.java:347)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:497)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket.access$900(Socket.java:30)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:300)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:124)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.Transport.onData(Transport.java:116)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket.access$300(WebSocket.java:29)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.transports.WebSocket$1$3.run(WebSocket.java:103)
>                                                      at com.github.nkzawa.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:75)
>                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

While requesting for room:

> [sendMessage]
>   {"type":"enter","mid":"fYtB6NY9nShtxyz","rid":"xyz_api_conference-143-4","receiveOnly":false,"agent":"Android","**version":"0.9.5**","userInfo":{"settings":{"audio":{"stereo":true},"video":{"resolution":{"height":480,"width":640},"frameRate":30}},"mediaStatus":{"audioMuted":false,"videoMuted":false},"userData":"videoCallUser"}}

but in response **[onMessage]** it just fall-down with above error message.

Any suggestion, if any new update?

Comment: Maybe the `version` parameter should be inside another object? Did you find documentation about this?